# Is it possible to run datanitro without opening excel

Tags: excel, datanitro

While it is possible to [run a datanitro script via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167920/can-i-set-up-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-datanitro-script), this still requires excel to be open.  Is it possible to have a .py file that executes datanitro (like opening and closing an excel file) without a human needing to be present to open excel and execute the script?

If it isn't possible yet is it in the works?

Answer (score 0):

DataNitro needs to have Excel open before you can run it, but you can have a script start automatically when a workbook is opened (https://datanitro.com/docs/scripts.html#autostart).

You can combine that with a Python script (outside of DataNitro) or other script to open and close the Excel file and launch the process automatically.